# Wordpress plugin archive

Tags: plugins

I need to find an archive of some Wordpress plugins.

Previous webmaster of the site installed some plugins and then made modifications to some of them. He did not document these modifications in any way, so I have no idea what was changed and where. There's also no contact with him. And now I need to upgrade Wordpress and its plugins - there's a security update released.

I could compare installed plugins to originals but I can't find an archive of old versions of these plugins anywhere. Is there any?

Comment: I'm not aware of any archive so I would be interested to see if anyone else knows it however did you lookup the plugins individually. A lot of plugin authors have the older versions on their own site or in github or equivalent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the plugins were hosted in the official [WordPress SVN repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins), you can download old versions directly if they're available by clicking the 'developer' tab on the relevant plugin page. e.g. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress/developers/ (scroll down to 'other versions').

If the plugins weren't hosted at WordPress.org, you'll need to contact the plugin developer directly.

Comment: This is about the only answer. Additionally, I would recommend getting a text editor or other software that will "diff" the files for you.